# How to select top 10 records from each category

Tags: sql-server, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table with fields

```
Hour,
PathId,
Duration,
Event,
CellId,
Channel
```

I have 50+ CellId. Each CellId has four PathId (i.e. 0, 1, 2, 3). Each PathId has many Events and Durations. Now I want to display the top 10 records (each PathId) for each CellId.

**Sample Table**

[image: SampleTable]

**Sample Output**

[image: SampleOutput]

Comment: You need to top 10 ordered by something right? Ordered by `duration descending` or perhaps `duration ascending `?

Comment: yes.I need top 10 record ordered by pathid or duration.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use [row_number()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx) in a derived table. Partition by `CellID` and use the order by as per your specification. In the main query you filter on `rn` to get the top 10 rows per category.

```
select T.CellID,
       T.PathID,
       T.Duration
from (
     select T.CellID,
            T.PathID,
            T.Duration,
            row_number() over(partition by T.CellID order by T.Duration desc) as rn
     from dbo.YourTable as T
     ) as T
where T.rn <= 10;
```

Comment: Mikael.. It's working fine.. But it take only 60 records.. I have 100+ cellid and 400+ pathid.. Each cellid have 4 pathid. Now my query is, If i select cellId 1 means, i should display  top 10 each pathid for that cellid...

Comment: You want 10 records from each category as per your title. What is a category? I assumed a category is the same as CellID. If category is something else, for instance CellID + PathID you just have to modify the partition by clause to include all columns that make a category `partition by T.CellID, T.PathID`.

Comment: CellId is category..

Comment: @ShanmugaVadivel Well it isn't...`CellID` and `PathID` is your category based on your initial question, so as Mikael says, `PARTITION BY T.CellID, T.PathID`

Comment: ok Mark.. I will try and let u know

Comment: Mark.. do you have any idea Without using row_number(),PARTITION BY functions..

Comment: Mikael and Mark Thank you very much.. It is working fine.. Once again Thank You Very Much...

Answer (score 4):

How about using [CROSS APPLY](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/boost-your-t-sql-with-the-apply-operator) eg

```
USE tempdb
GO

SET NOCOUNT ON
GO

IF OBJECT_ID('#tmp') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tmp
CREATE TABLE #tmp
(
    CellId      INT,
    PathId      INT,
    Duration    INT
)
GO

INSERT INTO #tmp VALUES
    ( 10, 1, 100 ),
    ( 10, 0, 120 ),
    ( 10, 2, 125 ),
    ( 10, 1, 111 ),
    ( 10, 0, 215 ),
    ( 10, 2, 22 ),
    ( 10, 0, 222 ),
    ( 10, 0, 55 ),
    ( 10, 1, 555 ),
    ( 10, 2, 58 ),
    ( 10, 0, 88 ),
    ( 10, 0, 9 ),
    ( 10, 2, 98 ),
    ( 10, 1, 55 ),
    ( 10, 2, 98 ),
    ( 10, 2, 74 ),
    ( 10, 0, 65 ),
    ( 10, 0, 66 ),
    ( 10, 1, 85 ),
    ( 10, 1, 37 ),
    ( 10, 1, 55 ),
    ( 11, 2, 11 ),
    ( 11, 0, 25 ),
    ( 11, 2, 69 ),
    ( 11, 0, 88 ),
    ( 11, 2, 54 ),
    ( 11, 0, 44 ),
    ( 11, 1, 22 ),
    ( 11, 0, 22 ),
    ( 11, 1, 55 ),
    ( 11, 1, 69 ),
    ( 11, 0, 55 ),
    ( 11, 1, 65 ),
    ( 11, 1, 65 ),
    ( 11, 0, 33 ),
    ( 11, 2, 35 )
GO


SELECT x.*
FROM ( SELECT DISTINCT cellId FROM #tmp ) c
    CROSS APPLY ( SELECT TOP 10 * FROM #tmp t WHERE c.cellId = t.cellId ) x
```

Comment: How to use group by inside Row_number() over (partition by ....order by)... It is possible?

Comment: Could you compare your solution to the "partition by" one, please? What's better to use, when, why etc.?

Comment: Nice one. I have tried more then 20 queries on 2.5 million records but your query is performing much fast.