# Select Top Ten Each Group

Tags: sql-server

This my table and and my query

!
[MyTable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mrjgC.png)

```
This is My query
select CellId, PathId, channel, sum(Duration) as min_duration 
from HourlySummary group by CellId, PathId, Channel  
order by cellid, pathid, sum(Duration) desc
```

In my table I have 50+ `cellid` and each `cellid` have four `pathid`(i.e, 0,1,2,3)

Now I want to display top 10 records (each `pathId`) for each `cellid` `order by Duaration`

Comment: Duplicate, flagged.

Comment: You already have a question about this where you accepted an answer.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you want to apply the top 10 per `cellID` scenario, just not to the base table but to the aggregated results. The answer is really very similar. You can use your results as a table (because it is a virtual table) - just remove the order by clause - then apply [@Mikael Eriksson's's solution](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/84157/how-to-select-top-10-records-from-each-category/84161#84161) and add the order by you want in the final output:

```
-- our results: a common table expression
; with YourTable as
  ( select CellId, PathId, Channel, sum(Duration) as SumDuration 
    from dbo.HourlySummary 
    group by CellId, PathId, Channel
  )
-- using the results and row numbering them to get top 10 per CellID
select T.CellID,
       T.PathID,
       T.Channel,
       T.SumDuration
from (
     select T.CellID,
            T.PathID,
            T.SumDuration,
            row_number() over(partition by T.CellID order by T.SumDuration desc) as rn
     from YourTable as T
     ) as T
where T.rn <= 10
order by CellID, PathID, SumDuration desc ;
```

---

You could also combine the two intermediate tables (the cte and the row numbering derived table) into one (cte or derived table), like this:

```
; with YourTable as
  ( select T.CellID,
           T.PathID,
           T.Channel,
           sum(T.Duration) as SumDuration,
           row_number() over(partition by T.CellID order by sum(T.Duration) desc) as rn
    from dbo.HourlySummary as T
    group by T.CellId, T.PathId, T.Channel
  )
select T.CellID,
       T.PathID,
       T.SumDuration,
       T.Channel,
from YourTable as T
where T.rn <= 10
order by CellID, PathID, SumDuration desc ;
```